# Passing object or Array List from one Fragment to another Fragment using Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass the object or the arrayList from this fragment to another. I was using the Intent method but I had the same problem which I do not know what parameter should I put in bundle.putParcelable() method.

```
BlankFragment1 sendData = new BlankFragment1();         
final Series s = new Series(itemName.getText().toString(),            
Integer.parseInt(itemYear.getText().toString())                 
,Integer.parseInt(itemNumberofSeas.getText().toString()),     
dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString());          
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();         
bundle.putParcelable(s);         
sendData.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **setArguments** to **add  the data** same as **putextra** in activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
bundles.putSerializable("KEY_ARRAYLIST", DIVID);
bundle.putString("longitude", longitude);
bundle.putString("board_id", board_id);
MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And to get data use **getArguments** same as **getExtra** in Activity

```
String latitude =  getArguments().getString("latitude")
 Arraylist obj=    getArguments().getSerializable("KEY_ARRAYLIST");
```